# How to export a layer without cropping my entire image

Tags: gimp, layers, crop

I often take screenshots, but then only want to export a portion of the screenshot instead of the entire thing. I know I can crop the image, but I was wondering if there was a way I could export a single layer that is smaller than the entire image without the export including the surrounding empty space that shows up despite having all my other layers turned off?

For instance, I have a canvas size of 5000px^2 containing a layer with size 317x72px. I want to maintain the canvas size because of other layers, so I've been cropping the whole image to the smaller layer, exporting, then undoing the cropping. I'd like to just export.

Comment: any specific application that you use?

Comment: I'm using Gimp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't think of a way to just save a layer in a picture (could be done with a script...). But there is a much more efficient way than your current one:

- Make layer active
- `Select>All`, `Edit>Copy`, `Edit>Paste as>New image`
- `File>Export`

Which, with the standard shortcuts, is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: Yeah, had a long conversation with my graphic design buddy last night who pretty much came to the same conclusion. It's inconvenient, but something like this will probably have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Previously to take a screen capture of your monitor use the print screen button on your keyboard and to capture the contents of a single window select it and hit ALT+PrintScreen

To save a screenshot of just a portion of your screen use the Snipping Tool. THis is freeware that comes with windows or microsoft gives it away from their site.

With Snipping Tool installed get your content up on your screen and open snipping tool. Select "New Snip" then draw a rectangle around the content you want.

There are pens to draw on your snip, very useful.
You can then save, copy or send your snip.

The save options allow .JPG and .PNG .GIF or .HTML.

To snip a picture on a Mac using your keyboard is quite simple, you hold the "Command, Shift and 4" together and then select what you want to do a screen shot of.

The fact is that the Mac came out with a "snipping tool" app before Windows did.

OS X comes with an app called Grab (as in "screen grab"), in your Utilities folder. It will let you do screen shots with your mouse instead of having to memorize the shortcuts. Just click the Capture menu and you will have the commands Selection, Window, Screen, and Timed Screen.

Comment: This is pretty much equivalent to the solution xenoid gave, so I'll give you the upvote, but I prefer to stay within one program at a time if I can help it.

Answer (score -1):

Toggle the visibility of the other layers by clicking on their eye in layers panel and save or export the visible layer.

Comment: From the question: "[...] I was wondering if there was a way I could export a single layer that is smaller than the entire image **without the export including the surrounding empty space that shows up despite having all my other layers turned off?**"